# Unable to Capture the Radio button values in the table upon Button Clicked

Tags: javascript, redux, react-hooks

I am unable to get the Radio button values when I submit the Form, Radio button value shows empty.
I used a separate function for radio button to capture the values and display in the Form,
But its shows Empty, What Mistake I am doing here, Please Can anyone help me in this, Thanks in advance

```
 const [data, setdata] = useState({
        "UserName": "",
        "PhoneNumber": "",
        "email": "",
        "dropDown": "",
        "gender": "",
        "checking": [],
    })

 const [radio, setradio] = useState([
        {name:"Male",isChecked:false},
        {name:"Female",isChecked:false}
    ])
```

This is the Radio button Function

```
   const handleGenderChange =(e) =>{
       let newRadio =[...radio]
        //console.log(e.target.value);
        radio.forEach((rf)=>{
               rf.isChecked =false;
               if(rf.name === e.target.value){
                   rf.isChecked = true;
               }
        });
        setradio(newRadio);
        //console.log(newRadio);
   }
```

This is the onSubmit Function

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        let newData = {...data};
                     radio.forEach((rs)=>{
                          if(rs.isChecked){
                              newData.gender = rs.name;
                          }
                     })
                     setdata(newData);
                     console.log(data);  
        dispatch(allActions.createData(data));
    }
```

Here is the UI

```
<label className="mb-2 fw-bold">Gender</label>
                                                {
                                                    radio.map((rd)=>(
                                                        <div className="form-check">
                                                        <input className="form-check-input" type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value={rd.name} onChange={handleGenderChange} />
                                                        <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="flexRadioDefault1" >{rd.name}</label>
                                                    </div>
                                                    ))
                                                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your "handleGenderChange" function to look like this:

```js
   const handleGenderChange =(e) =>{
       let newRadio =[...radio]
        //console.log(e.target.value);
        newRadio.map((rf)=>{
               rf.isChecked =false;
               if(rf.name === e.target.value){
                   rf.isChecked = true;
               }
               return rf;
        });
        setradio(newRadio);
        //console.log(newRadio);
   }
```

Explanation:

1. Spread operator (...) does only shallow copy
2. forEach function only iterates through array members. If you need to do any modifications to those members, use a map method instead.

Comment: Glad I could help :)